# concmath-OTF and eulervm lead to problems in math mode

Tags: debugging, opentype, eulervm

I'm trying to use the recently-released `concmath-otf` package in a combination with `eulervm`, instead of the `concrete` package. My goal was to replace `concrete roman` with the more modern opentype version, that is: to set `concmath-otf` as the main text font and `eulervm` as the math font. (I'm probably mistaking the package names with the font names, but I hope you get the idea.)

However, this combination makes all letters in math mode invisible, while normal text looks fine.

What may be the reason? Are there any solutions?

---

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% using/not using these two packages makes
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % EXACTLY no visual difference in the output

\usepackage{concmath-otf}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

  Text looks normal. But
  \begin{equation} 2 M + a + t + h^2 \end{equation}
  does not look so good.

\end{document}
```

The results:

**LuaLaTeX:**
[image: LuaLaTeX]

**XeLaTeX:**
[image]
Both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX compile without errors and give this warning:

```
Package eulervm Warning: Unknown Operator Encoding! Math accents may be wrong: assuming OT1 positions.
```

... and this warning, if `inputenc` is used:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

pdfLaTeX does not compile.
I'm using MiKTex 2.9 (I think), on Windows 10.

Comment: never use inputenc or fontenc packages with xelatex or lualatex

Comment: eulevm package also looks like it assumes classic tex not luatex/xetex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

concmath-otf is as the name says mainly for math and is not compatible with eulervm as both tries to setup math but with different methods (unicode-math version legacy math).

If you want to use only the text font use fontspec:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{cmunorm.otf}
    [BoldFont =       cmunobx.otf ,
     ItalicFont =     cmunoti.otf ,
     BoldItalicFont = cmunobi.otf
    ]

\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

  Text looks normal. But
  \begin{equation} 2 M + a + t + h^2 \end{equation}
  does not look so good.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) font is not really complete, but if you have it, it can do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{concmath-otf}

\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[range={up,it}]

\begin{document}

Text looks normal. And
\begin{equation}
2 M + a + t + h^2
\end{equation}
looks good.

\end{document}
```

[image]